# What city on Earth does the final battle take place in in Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Right before you rush into that beam to be transported onto the Citadel, where does that take place?

What city on Earth does the final battle take place in in Mass Effect 3?

Answer (score 5):

The Game Wiki for the final mission contains some [trivia](https://masseffect.fandom.com/wiki/Priority:_Earth#Trivia) which states:

> The mission begins on the left bank of the River Thames. The river and downed bridges can be seen both from the drop-off point and a few other locations you can reach during early lulls in the fighting. The position of Big Ben shows which bank you're on, and it can be established that the mission starts at approximately the present-day location of the Embankment and Hungerford bridges.

Using this information, you can deduce that it is **London, England**.  There is also a screenshot on the page that show [Big Ben](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Ben) in the background:

[image: big ben clock tower]